# Inserting remote(internet) xml file in SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xml-parsing

This is my big problem. Based on the options I've googled, one is parsing the data i needed then store in sqlite and the other is by storing the whole xml file as text in sqlite. I actually don't know how where to start,but I think the second option is preferable for me.. Can anyone point me on how am I gonna do this?Or if there are more suggestions regarding my problem here..

Any reply will be much appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: depends on your condition you can use any option. But normally the first option is better you parse the data & then store that data in db

Comment: How exactly will I do this? Can you point me in a tutorial for this one? I'm just new in sqlite database.

Oh,thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but my English is not very good.

I would choose the second option. You can read a file XML with XmlPullParser and XmlPullParserFactory:

```
    XmlPullParser xmlPullParser;  
    String output; 
    XmlPullParserFactory fabrica = null;

    File archivoXml = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + servicioXML); //servicioXML is a xml path 
    FileInputStream fisArchivo = null;
    XmlPullParser analizador = null;
    int tipoEvento = 0; 

    try {
        fisArchivo = new FileInputStream(archivoXml);
        fabrica = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        fabrica.setNamespaceAware(true);
        analizador = fabrica.newPullParser();
        analizador.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fisArchivo));
        fabrica = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();  
        xmlPullParser = fabrica.newPullParser();  
        xmlPullParser.setInput(fisArchivo, "UTF-8"); 
        tipoEvento = xmlPullParser.getEventType(); 

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (tipoEvento != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {  
        analizarEvento(tipoEvento);  
        try {  
            tipoEvento = xmlPullParser.next();  
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    } 
}  


private void analizarEvento(int evento){  
    switch (evento) {  
    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:  
        break;  

    case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:    
        break;  

    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:   
        break;  

    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:  
        break;  

    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:  
        output = xmlPullParser.getText();  
        AdapterBBDD.setDBField(output); //add the xml data to the database
        break;  
    }
```

More info: [XmlPullParser in Android](http://www.happygeek.in/xmlpullparser-in-android)

Comment: Maybe you have examples in DOM parser? Because almost all of my activity uses DOM..If you have one,please post your answer here..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better if you parse the data once and store in the database. U can query only the required data and display.

```
 SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                    /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
                    XMLHandler dbXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(dbXMLHandler);
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                            xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(is));

    phoneList = XMLHandler.phoneList;
                for(int id = 0; id < phoneList.getID().size();id++)
                {
                    database.open();
                    database.insertupdateintoPhonebook(phoneList.getUserName().get(id),
                            phoneList.getUserName().get(id)
                                    .get(id), phoneList.getDOB().get(id)

                    database.close();
}
```

and the DBXMLHAndler.java is as follows

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;



public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler{
Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = null;
public static Phonelist phoneList = null;

public static Phonelist getPhoneList() {
    return phoneList;
}

public static void setPhonelist(Phonelist phoneList) {
    DBXMLHandler.phoneList = phoneList;
}
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("NewDataSet"))
    {
        phoneList = new Phonelist();
    }

}

/** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
 * -- </name> )*/
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */ 
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Id"))
        phoneList.setID(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Username"))
        phoneList.setUserName(currentValue);    
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Dob"))
        phoneList.setDOB(currentValue);

}

/** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name> 
 * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you have examples in DOM parser? Because almost all of my activity uses DOM..If you have one,please post your answer here..thanks!